# Clothing creating sock

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I watched some tutorials how to create shirts and such, my problem is I want to create a sock, so I made a duplicate of a part of the foot, separated it and made it larger, I want to solidify it later. However how do I easily join those toes so I can sculpt it?

[image: How do I merge those toes to sculpt a sock?]

I even tried too look for tutorials but I find only finger less gloves, shirts, jeans, but never socks. 
When I go sculpt mode I I can't fill those gaps, between each toe, if I do and use smooth they get their old form back. Any hint would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should duplicate a single edge loop around the ankle, and then extrude, move, scale and rotate it until you have the entire foot covered. Because of the geometry of feet, it's more efficient to take the time and model the sock, rather than try and base it off the geometry of the foot.